# Can tags in Rspec be ANDed or ORed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber

In Cucumber, I had something like this

```
@do_this
@de @fr @it @us
Scenario: Do something irrelevant
Given ...
When ...
Then

@do_that
@de @fr @it @us
Scenario: Do a different irrelevant thing
Given ...
When ...
Then
```

It was possible to do something like `cucumber -t @de -t @do_this`, so only scenarios which matched both tags would be run. I can't seem to get the same behavior in Rspec, though. In the above example, only the first scenario would run, even though the second one also has a `@de` tag.

Background: I have a platform which is rolled out in many countries, and not all features are available in every country. So the nice thing was that I could just tag the scenarios accordingly, and then call individual scenarios from the command line. I am currently in the process of switching to Rspec from Cucumber because of several reasons, but this is the only thing holding me back at the moment. Of course I am also open for other suggestions on how to approach this.

Short version: I would like to call individual tests in Rspec who match two or more tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RSpec tag expressions are only ORed for inclusion and ANDed for exclusion, so you can't do what you want in general. Further, it appears that you can use *either* tag filters or a filter on the example descriptions, but not both, so I think that combining those two techniques is out as well. (Perhaps someone can correct me on this).

However, if you have a limited/structured situation implied by your example, I think you can do the following:

- Define a boolean tag for each of the languages and use the traditional inclusion filter
- Define a `do` tag with values of `this`, `that`, etc. and use a `lambda` exclusion filter which will exclude everything *but* the value(s) you want.

If you do the above, you will be able so specify examples which contain any of the languages you want *and* whatever subset of the `do` values you want

However, I doubt there is a way to specify the `lambda` expression format in the command line so I think you're limited to using the configuration option approach. In any event, see http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration:filter_run_excluding for a description of the underlying capability.

That's a lot of limitations, I know. This seems like an area where RSpec could be fairly easily extended, so perhaps we'll see extensions in the future.